# Help required in finding solution to overdetermined system of equations?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, systems-of-equations

I have access to M probability measures, $P_e(c_1),P_e(c_2),\cdots,P_e(c_M)$, defined as
\begin{equation}
P_e(x) = p(x|y) = p(y|x)\cdot \mathbb{P}(X=x) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \exp\Big[-\frac{(y-\alpha x)^2}{2\sigma^2}\Big] \mathbb{P}(X=x),
\end{equation}
where $x\in\{c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_M\}$ and is discrete. $p(x|y)$ is a PMF

I need to estimate $\sigma^2,\alpha,y$ from these M probabilities.I understand that this is an overdetermined system and therefore has no consistent solution. But how can I find a reasonable estimate of these quantities.

**Side note:** Additional constraints that might be helpful are:

1. $\sum _{i=1}^{M} P_e(c_i)=1 $
2. $\alpha>0$
3. $\sigma\in\mathbb{R}, \sigma>0$

Comment: Are you sure that probability density function is normalized?

Comment: Yes, it is normalized. This fact lead to first constraint that the sum of all probabilities equal 1

Comment: Is $p(x\,|\,y)$ normalized, though? You are sampling a PDF, aren't you?

Comment: I fixed the normalization constant.

Comment: Shouldn't the normalization constant contain $\alpha$? Note that the variable is $x$.

Comment: I don't think so. Can you write down what you think is correct?

Comment: Note that $$\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\alpha x - y}{\sigma}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{x - \alpha^{-1} y}{\alpha^{-1} \sigma}\right)^2$$Hence, the variance is $\alpha^{-2} \sigma^2$.

Comment: ok. but the question remains can i estimate $y,\alpha,\sigma$ from these probabilities?

Comment: They're not probabilities. They're probability **densities**. They can be larger than $1$, after all.

Comment: ok. i appreciate you for bringing this up. but the question still remains ....

Comment: Your question is ill-posed. Is $P_e$ a PDF or a PMF? Is $x$ discrete or continuous?

Comment: If we have a Gaussian PMF, then the normalization factor is not $\frac {1}{\sqrt {2 \pi \sigma ^{2}}}$.

Comment: Take a look at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83022/how-to-fit-data-that-looks-like-a-gaussian and http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/gaussian.html

Answer (score 1):

*Since I am very bad with probabilities, this answer could be totally stupid and, depending on comments, I should delete it.*

It seems to me that, having $n$ data points $(x_i,P_i)$, the problem is relevant from nonlinear regression; one of the issues is to first obtain reasonable estimates for the parameters $\sigma^2,\alpha,y$. So, take logarithms first and rearrange the expression. We then have $$\log(P)=-\left(\log(\pi \sigma^2)+\frac{y^2}{\sigma^2}\right)+\frac{2\alpha y}{\sigma^2} x-\frac{\alpha^2}{\sigma^2}x^2$$ Defining $z=\log(P)$, we then face a quadratic model $$z=A+B x+Cx^2$$ which is easy to fit using ordinary least square method $(z_i=\log(P_i))$. When parameters $(A,B,C)$ have been found we then have to solve $$C=-\frac{\alpha^2}{\sigma^2}\tag1$$ $$B=\frac{2\alpha y}{\sigma^2}\tag2$$ $$A=-\left(\log(\pi \sigma^2)+\frac{y^2}{\sigma^2}\right)\tag3$$  which can easily be solved using successive eliminations.

Using these estimates, you have all elements for starting a nonlinear regression (you need to do it since what is measured is $P$ and not any of its possible transforms such as $\log(P)$.

If , for any reason, you do not want (or cannot) use nonlinear regression, you could use [this method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingExponential.html) extending it to three parameters (this is simple to do).

Now, the problem is the constraint. If you need to take it into account, I am afraid that you would need a nonlinear optimization (the objective function being the sum of the squares of the residuals) able to handle constraints.